# Defining the login URL with [Authorize] attribute

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a private-pages-only application in MVC4.

I successfully (almost successfully) created the login page using a custom Membership provider based on NHibernate and my domain's entities/repositories.

Every controller but `AuthController` is marked with `[Authorize]`.

The webapp is supposed to redirect me to the login page when I'm not authorized. I created the whole app from scratch, so I know that nowhere I'll find the `AuthController` to be declared as landing URL for unauthenticated users.

#### How to tell MVC that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the built-in forms authentication, the URL goes into `web.config`, in the `loginUrl` attribute of the `forms` element.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.71).aspx

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/membership/login" />
    </authentication> 
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I was so dumb thinking that MVC doesn't use "forms" authentication, or better that "forms" authentication was relegated to the old world of WebForms

Comment: @djechelon: How did you log the user in if not by using the `FormsAuthentication` class? At any rate, many things (such as membership, roles, profiles and authentication) that aren't directly related to presentation will work exactly the same with MVC.

Comment: I directly typed the login URL for debug purposes until now :) Anyway I use Membership class to "ValidateUser"

Comment: @djechelon: But `ValidateUser` doesn't actually log the user in, all it does is verify the username and password. Or didn't you implement setting a login cookie yet in the first place?

Comment: I have only verified that the controller follows the correct flows in case of correct/wrong password. Let me anticipate the next SO question: **how the hell do I login a user using Membership/FormsAuthentication/whatever**? In other words, how do I tell AuthorizeAttribute that there is currently a user logged in? By manually setting Context.Request.User? Hmmm...........

Comment: If you want to read up before asking that question, try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx . The methods you want are FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie or RedirectFromLoginPage (after checking the password using ValidateUser). The latter method does the same as the former, but also takes care of redirecting the user to the correct return URL, if specified.